# Standard HTTP header to indicate location of OpenID Connect server?

Tags: http, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

We're developing a native application that accesses content on a resource server (which is also under our control). The resource server will require the user of the native app to authenticate by OpenID Connect to get an access key which is passed as a bearer token (RFC 6750). The authorization server is a separate server running Keycloak.

I'd like to avoid hard-coding information into the client software about the address of the authorization server. Instead, I'd like the resource server to provide the link to the auth server's provider discovery endpoint, possibly as part of the HTTP 401 challenge. I could just invent an X-MyApp-* header, but I was wondering if there is an established convention for this (whether an HTTP header, body content in the 401 response, a standard URL on the resource server etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RFC6750 define the usage of WWW-Authenticate Response Header.

[Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-3) of the spec define follow,

> If the protected resource request does not include authentication
> credentials or does not contain an access token that enables access
> to the protected resource, the resource server MUST include the HTTP
> "WWW-Authenticate" response

You may utilise this header to respond back the address of the authorization server. Specification allows to have attributes other than the ones defined by specification,

> All challenges defined by this specification MUST use the auth-scheme
> value "Bearer".  This scheme MUST be followed by one or more
> auth-param values.  The auth-param attributes used or defined by this
> specification are as follows.  **Other auth-param attributes MAY be
> used as well**.

Now if we can define a custom attribute named **auth_server**, then we can add it to 401 response's WWW-Authenticate header as below

**`WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="example", auth_server="URL-TO-OIDC-SERVER"`**

Your client must parse the header and extract the auth_server value .

Comment: Do you mean as one of the key=value pairs? Is there a standard key to use or should I make one up?

Comment: @BruceMerry yes, you can use a similar approach. I updated my answer with an example. I have practically seen this in use as well.